# ngx-bootstrap datepicker - disable specific days (tuesdays, 15th, ..)

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I have situation where i want to disable all days except *15th*, *20th* and *25th* in every month.

**Is that possible ?** Is there any function to do that ?

Comment: No, there's no such possibility for now. There is a feature request for it so it will be implemented in next releases

Comment: Thank you. Going to wait then..

Comment: Here it is: [v2.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/pull/2744)